# Tendermint : get error when start tendermint node as per the sample

Tags: blockchain, tendermint

I tried to create a application as per the guild in the [tendermint document](https://docs.tendermint.com/master/tutorials/go.html).

After I started the application and tendermint node, getting the below error. I use go version go1.15.5 linux/amd64 and tednermint v0.34.0-rc4-148-g095e9cd.

```
[bc@localhost kvstore]$ TMHOME="/tmp/example" tendermint node --proxy_app=unix://example.sock
I[2020-12-01|13:16:59.697] Version info                                 module=main software=v0.34.0-rc4-148-g095e9cd block=11 p2p=8
I[2020-12-01|13:16:59.702] Starting Node service                        module=main impl=Node
I[2020-12-01|13:16:59.703] Starting StateSync service                   module=statesync impl=StateSync
I[2020-12-01|13:16:59.738] Started node                                 module=main nodeInfo="{ProtocolVersion:{P2P:8 Block:11 App:0} DefaultNodeID:3cf5ea6219c57fd906c042f767748988ba070db7 ListenAddr:tcp://0.0.0.0:26656 Network:test-chain-1mrgVg Version:v0.34.0-rc4-148-g095e9cd Channels:40202122233038606100 Moniker:localhost.localdomain Other:{TxIndex:on RPCAddress:tcp://127.0.0.1:26657}}"
E[2020-12-01|13:17:00.758] Stopping abci.socketClient for error: read message: EOF module=abci-client connection=consensus
E[2020-12-01|13:17:00.758] consensus connection terminated. Did the application crash? Please restart tendermint module=proxy err="read message: EOF"
E[2020-12-01|13:17:00.758] Error in proxyAppConn.BeginBlock             module=state err="read message: EOF"
E[2020-12-01|13:17:00.758] Error on ApplyBlock                          module=consensus err="read message: EOF"
I[2020-12-01|13:17:00.758] captured terminated, exiting...              module=main 
I[2020-12-01|13:17:00.758] Stopping Node service                        module=main impl=Node
I[2020-12-01|13:17:00.758] Stopping Node                                module=main 
I[2020-12-01|13:17:00.760] Stopping StateSync service                   module=statesync impl=StateSync
I[2020-12-01|13:17:00.760] Closing rpc listener                         module=main listener="&{Listener:0xc00000d440 sem:0xc000039200 closeOnce:{done:0 m:{state:0 sema:0}} done:0xc000039260}"
E[2020-12-01|13:17:00.760] Error serving server                         module=main err="accept tcp 127.0.0.1:26657: use of closed network connection"
```

KVStore

```
[bc@localhost kvstore]$ ./example 
badger 2020/12/01 13:16:55 INFO: All 0 tables opened in 0s
badger 2020/12/01 13:16:55 INFO: Replaying file id: 0 at offset: 0
badger 2020/12/01 13:16:55 INFO: Replay took: 6.807µs
badger 2020/12/01 13:16:55 DEBUG: Value log discard stats empty
I[2020-12-01|13:16:55.373] Starting ABCIServer service                  impl=ABCIServer
I[2020-12-01|13:16:55.405] Waiting for new connection...                
I[2020-12-01|13:16:59.692] Accepted a new connection                    
I[2020-12-01|13:16:59.692] Waiting for new connection...                
I[2020-12-01|13:16:59.692] Accepted a new connection                    
I[2020-12-01|13:16:59.692] Waiting for new connection...                
I[2020-12-01|13:16:59.692] Accepted a new connection                    
I[2020-12-01|13:16:59.692] Waiting for new connection...                
I[2020-12-01|13:16:59.692] Accepted a new connection                    
I[2020-12-01|13:16:59.692] Waiting for new connection...                
E[2020-12-01|13:17:00.758] Connection error                             err="error reading message: proto: wrong wireType = 2 for field Height"
E[2020-12-01|13:17:00.761] Connection was closed by client              
E[2020-12-01|13:17:00.761] Connection was closed by client              
E[2020-12-01|13:17:00.761] Connection was closed by client
```

go.mod

```
module github.com/me/example

go 1.15

require (
    github.com/dgraph-io/badger v1.6.2
    github.com/tendermint/tendermint v0.34.0-rc4
)
```

Comment: opened https://github.com/tendermint/tendermint/issues/5735. thanks!

Comment: try Tendermint v0.34.0, not the latest master: `git checkout v0.34.0`. it worked for me

Comment: @melekes thank it work with v0.34.0.